# Similar code, yet one version does not return a String when it should

Tags: java, string, for-loop, types, alphabetical

For a class exercise, both my friend and I wrote a similar code. Hers works while mine gives out:

Error: This method must return a result of type java.lang.String

Her code :

```
 public static String alphaString (String a, String b) {

    for (int i=0; i<a.length(); i++){
      if ((int)(a.charAt(i)) < ((int)(b.charAt(i)))) {
        return a;
      }
      if ((int)(a.charAt(i)) > ((int)(b.charAt(i)))) {  
        return b;
      }
    }

    return ("these are the same words") ;

  }
```

My code :

// method that takes two Strings and returns the one that comes first in the alphabet

// alphaString("banana", "apple")--> "apple"

// alphaString("snake", "squirrel")--> "snake".

```
public static String alphaString(String s1, String s2) {


for (int i = 0; i<s1.length(); i++ ) {
    if (s1.charAt(i)<s2.charAt(i)) {
        return s1;
    }
    if (s1.charAt(i)>s2.charAt(i)){
        return s2;

    }


}
```

Now, I can tell that our variables are named differently and that she uses (int) (though I don't think it is necessary). I don't understand why her code works and mine not. If I try to also add the (int) and make the code even more similar, I still get the error.

Does anyone have any idea why that might be?

Comment: What is the last statement of her method? What is the last statement of your method? What is the difference?

Comment: What would her method return if the first string was empty (length 0)?  What would yours return?

Comment: @David mine wouldn't return anything at all because of the error, while hers would return "these are the same words"

Comment: @PatriciaManarazan: *"mine wouldn't return anything at all"* - That *is* the error.  The compiler has to ensure that the method will always return the advertised type.  There exists a logical condition where your method wouldn't return anything, which is invalid.

Comment: @camickr hers: return ("these are the same words") ; mine: return s2;

Comment: @PatriciaManarazan, So  what is the difference? Where is her last return statement? Where is your last return statement? What does your code return if the strings are equal?

Comment: @camrick In that situation, her code returns the quote in the last statement. Her last statement is outside of the for loop, which is what confuses me. If it's outside of the for loop shouldn't "these are the same words" always be returned? Sorry if this sounds trivial

Comment: @David but if we add "return "these are the same words"; " outside of the for loop why isn't it returned every time? I tough of adding an extra else-statement with the same return statement as my friend. But again it doesn't work. It seems that it has to be outside of the for loop for it to work, which puzzles me.

Comment: @PatriciaManarazan: Again, what happens in your code if the for loop is never entered?  The method would return nothing.  But it must return *something*.  Under all logical conditions it must return something.  The error you’re getting is the compiler enforcing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing the *default* return of `"these are the same words"`. It isn't clear why you both chose to implement this with a loop (or why neither of you chose to use an `else`). Regardless, `String` is `Comparable` so I would simply do

```
public static String alphaString(String s1, String s2) {
    int c = s1.compareTo(s2);
    if (c < 0) {
        return s1;
    } else if (c > 0) {
        return s2;
    }
    return "these are the same words";
}
```

Comment: We used a loop because that was the direction our teacher gave us and we have not seen s1.compareTo(s2) formally in class, so we were not allowed.

Comment: When I add : return "these are the same words";      to my original method I can make it compile and It does return a String but I don't understand why. How does that statement affect the rest? why does its absence cause the error?

Comment: The method advertises that it returns a String, therefore, every possible exit out of the method must return a String. In the case where both of the if conditions evaluate to false, there is not a return statement. Therefore, there is a possible exit out of the method that does not return a String, which is the reason for the compile error.